# rails uniqueness to boolean attribute

Tags: validation, unique

My problem is this:
I have a association table, I need to do a validation that accepts only a TRUE as value for the 'princial' column, for each `person_id`, no matter how many FALSE values may exist for `person_id`.

I tried following a rails validation as follows:

`validates :principal, uniqueness: { scope: :person_id }`

Unfortunately, the validation is not working. The bank is allowing more than one record with the value TRUE to principal, with the same person_id

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no choice but to create a custom validation

```
validate :validate_principal_uniqueness

def validate_principal_uniqueness
  errors.add(:principal, "should be uniq") if YourModel.where(principal: true).any?
end
```

references: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

hope it helps